# Does not get the distance from colorized_depth image in d435i

Tags: python, distance

I want to get the distance from colorized_depth image. But the output from my colorized image is show value [r g b] instead of distance,Z. So I would like to ask what can I do to solve the problem?
I get the distance by
Distance = depth_frame[point [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tunnd.jpg), point[0]]
It is same if i use:
Distance = depth_frame.getDistance[point [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tunnd.jpg), point[0]]
Thank you for your help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tunnd.jpg)